# How to quickly compute the Jordan Matrix for this $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

Now I've learnt how to compute the Jordan matrix of a $2\times 2$ block. I wonder how you can do this fast without numerical tools.

Let my matrix be:

$A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & −1 &1 & 0\\
1 &  0 &0 & 1\\
0 &  0 &0 &−1\\
0 &  0 &1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Does anyone know how to quickly compute the Jordan Block Matrix for this matrix $A$ ?

Comment: As an aside: I'm fairly sure there's no such thing as *quickly* computing the Jordan form of a matrix.

Comment: I thought I could divide this into four separate blocks and compute the Jordan form separately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$ to get
$$L^4 + 2L^2 + 1 = 0$$
which is a biquadratic which can be quickly solved to get the roots $[i, i, -i, -i]$, so the Jordan form is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
i & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -i & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
\end{bmatrix}$$